# retrieve parent text on click (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select first **td** element, when button "**Add**" is clicked.

```
              <tr>
                <td>tt3783958</td>
                <td>La La Land</td>
                <td>2016</td>
                <td>Comedy, Drama, Music</td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Add</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn.btn-outline-success").eq(0).click(function() {
    var test = $(this).parent().parent().find("td").first()
    console.log(test)
    var fest = $(this).find("td").first()
    console.log(fest)
  });
});
```

> **Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ma1Lac9v/2/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `eq(0)`. `eq(0)` means selector with zero index, so add event to only first button. You can use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function to select first parent element with your selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn.btn-outline-success").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).closest("tr").find('td').first().text()
    console.log(test)
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-inverse">
              <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Option</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>tt3783958</td>
                <td>La La Land</td>
                <td>2016</td>
                <td>Comedy, Drama, Music</td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Add</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>tt0488120</td>
                <td>Fracture</td>
                <td>2007</td>
                <td>Crime, Drama, Mystery</td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Add</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>tt3569230</td>
                <td>Legend</td>
                <td>2015</td>
                <td>Biography, Crime, Drama</td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Add</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>tt2692904</td>
                <td>Locke</td>
                <td>2013</td>
                <td>Drama</td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Add</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>tt1392190</td>
                <td>Mad Max: Fury Road</td>
                <td>2015</td>
                <td>Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi</td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Add</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>tt0993846</td>
                <td>The Wolf of Wall Street</td>
                <td>2013</td>
                <td>Biography, Comedy, Crime</td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Add</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well if you check Live Demo, I need it, because I have multiple buttons.

Comment: You can call `text()` to get text of element.

Comment: Your answer makes no sense

Comment: I added snippets. Did you mean? @SilverSurfer

Comment: And if u have 100 parents? It is better `closest()`

Comment: I think the question not about selector and I answer to this question, but add closest function to improve the answer. Thank you for your advance. @SilverSurfer

Answer (score 2):

You can select the [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) tr and then the first td:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find("td:first")
```

```js
$(".btn.btn-outline-success").on('click', function(e) {
    var test = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:first");
    console.log(test.text());
});
```

```html
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-inverse">
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Option</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>tt3783958</td>
                    <td>La La Land</td>
                    <td>2016</td>
                    <td>Comedy, Drama, Music</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>tt0488120</td>
                    <td>Fracture</td>
                    <td>2007</td>
                    <td>Crime, Drama, Mystery</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>tt3569230</td>
                    <td>Legend</td>
                    <td>2015</td>
                    <td>Biography, Crime, Drama</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>tt2692904</td>
                    <td>Locke</td>
                    <td>2013</td>
                    <td>Drama</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>tt1392190</td>
                    <td>Mad Max: Fury Road</td>
                    <td>2015</td>
                    <td>Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>tt0993846</td>
                    <td>The Wolf of Wall Street</td>
                    <td>2013</td>
                    <td>Biography, Comedy, Crime</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```